# ATI: No launcher or top bar in 12.10

Tags: unity, ati, 12.10

After upgrading to 12.10, I see no side bar or top bar. If I do unity restart, then Compiz crashes (I get a window telling me that and I can send an error report).

I have ATI mobility Radeon 2400 and I have uninstalled the "fg-something" extra drivers (because I had the same problems with that installed).

Also, in case it's related, the display resolution is no longer set to the native resolution of the screen.

How can I get the launcher and top bar to load properly at startup?

Comment: Same for me, Mobility Radeon HD 5400

Answer (score 4):

Same for me; temporary work-around:

When at the login screen (hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and log out to get there), switch to terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and log in.

Run these commands to remove the `fglrx` driver:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglRx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev* xorg-driver-fglrx
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo reboot
```